# Function to replace multiple characters

Tags: python

My code:

```
def replaces(_str:str,a=list,b=list):
    output = ''
    for num,i in enumerate(_str):
        output += i.replace(a[num],b[num])
    return output
```

but it outputs this:

```
>>> print(replaces('12345',['1','2','3'],['one','two','three']))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\+ Project\beat_machine\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    text = replaces('12345',['1','2','3'],['one','two','three'])
  File "g:\+ Project\beat_machine\test.py", line 4, in replaces
    output += i.replace(a[num],b[num])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `_str` has a length of 5, but the lists are only length of 3 which is why you are going out of range.

Comment: This code is rather broken though: `_str` signals 'this variable is private'; this isn't an error, but is very odd.  If you need to avoid shadowing builtins, use a *trailing* underscore, but here a better name isn't hard to think of. `a=list` assigns a to *the builtin `list`*; which makes no sense; you probably meant `a:list`.  Lastly is there any reason not to just use the builtin `str.replace()`?  I bet it's faster.

Comment: Even closer to this functionality than `replace` would be [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Comment: you should rather use `zip(a,b)` in something like `for before, after in zip(a,b): text = text.replace(before, after)`

Answer (score 1):

To map a set of strings to a different set of strings, it would be easiest to create a mapping dict and use `re.sub` with all the source strings joined into an alternation pattern and with a replacement function that returns the mapped value of each match:

```
import re

def replaces(s, a, b):
    mapping = dict(zip(a, b))
    return re.sub('|'.join(map(re.escape, a)), lambda m: mapping[m[0]], s)
```

so that:

```
print(replaces('12345',['1','2','3'],['one','two','three']))
```

outputs:

```
onetwothree45
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/PlumpGrossManagement

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use `zip(a,b)` to crete pairs and use these paris in `replace()`

```
def replaces(_str:str, a=list, b=list):
    output = _str
    for old_item, new_item in zip(a, b):
        output = output.replace(old_item, new_item)
    return output

print(replaces('12345',['1','2','3'],['one','two','three']))
```

Or you could create dictionary `{'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three'}` and later use `.get(key, default)` with old value as `default`

```
def replaces(_str:str, a=list, b=list):

    data = dict(zip(a, b))
    
    output = ""
    for old_item in _str:
        new_item = data.get(old_item, old_item)
        output += new_item
    return output

print(replaces('12345',['1','2','3'],['one','two','three']))
```

It similar to

```
    for old_item in _str:
        if old_item in data:
            new_item = data[old_item]
        else:
            new_item = old_item
        output += new_item
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a dictionary or table and use the translate to convert your string.

```
def replaces(_str:str, a=list, b=list):
    trans = {ord(k):v for k, v in  zip(a, b)}
    return _str.translate(trans)
```

Comment: this input `replaces('one two three four five',['one','two','three'],['1','2','3'])` will break your code too

Comment: Sure, this is for the template which has been presented on the question where a is the list of characters, and to use built-in translate method to efficiently replace, otherwise, there should be other approaches to be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replaces(s:str,a=list,b=list)->str:
    return " ".join([dict(zip(a,b)).get(i,i) for i in s.split()]) if ' ' in s else "".join([dict(zip(a,b)).get(i,i) for i in s])  

print(replaces('one two three four five',['one','two','three'],['1','2','3']))      # 1 2 3 four five
print(replaces('12345',['1','2','3'],['one','two','three']))                        # onetwothree45
```

Comment: The OP did not state that the input list always consists of single-character strings, so this approach will break when it doesn't.

Comment: @blhsing I'm sorry, English is far from being my first language, could you please provide example of input will brake the function?

Comment: For example, `replaces('one two thee four five',['one','two','three'],['1','2','3'])`.

Comment: @blhsing, thank you for marking my error, I've updated my answer, now it works right, doesn't it?